# Independence of union of disjoint intersection of independent events

Tags: probability, independence

I have a family of mutually independent events $(B_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$, each having the same probability. For $k \in \mathbb N$, let $A_k$ be event "$k$ consecutive $B_i$'s occur between steps $2^k$ and $2^{k+1} - 1$".

I came across this situation in an exercise and the solution said $(A_k)_k$ was *obviously* mutually independent.

I formally defined $A_k$ as follows:

$$A_k = \bigcup_{i = 2^k}^{2^{k + 1} - k} \bigcap_{j = i}^{i + k - 1} B_j.$$

From that definition, I'm struggling to find a proof of the claim that $(A_k)$ is independent.

---

I showed that if $(C_i)$ is mutually independent and $(I_k)$ is a partition of $\mathbb N$ then:

$$\left(\bigcup_{i \in I_k} C_i\right)_{k \in \mathbb N}$$

is mutually independent.
However, it doesn't seem to help in my situation. The hypothesis that $(C_i)$ is mutually independent is too strong since $\bigcap_{j = i}^{i + k - 1} B_j$ and $\bigcap_{j = p}^{p + k - 1} B_j$ are not necessarily independent (take $B_4 \cap B_5$ and $B_5 \cap B_6$, when $k = 2$).

I tried to prove the following, more general claim, which I believed would allow me to prove the initial statement:

If $(I_k)$ is a partition of $\mathbb N$ and $(B_i)$ are "independent with respect to $(I_k)$" (in the sense that if $n_1 \in I_1, n_2 \in I_2, ...$ then $(B_{n_1}, B_{n_2}, ...)$ is mutually independent), then:

$$\left(\bigcup_{i \in I_k} B_i\right)_{k}$$

is mutually independent.

However, this doesn't seem to be correct as I could find an example where three events $A$, $B$ and $C$ are such that $A$ is independent of $C$, $B$ is independent of $C$ and $(A \cup B)$ is not independent of $C$.

Any confirmation that the initial claim is true and help towards a proof would be appreciated.

Comment: Are your events mutually independent (every two are independent, also called pairwise independence), or jointly independent? It seems like in your counterexample, you only have pairwise independence(?).

Comment: All I assumed was that $A$ and $C$ were independent and that $B$ and $C$ were independent. However your comment made me think that we could certainly assume something stronger: for every family of $B_i$'s indexed by some $J$, it looks like we have $\mathbb P(\bigcap_{i \in J} B_i) = \prod_{k \in \mathbb N} \mathbb P(\bigcap_{i \in J \cap I_k} B_i)$.